# Checking if excel was turned on for the first time today(VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function difference_dat (returns in days the difference of current date and given date). The result (increases by 1 every day) is in A1.

I am going to create a table and search for information in it.
I came up with Number of tables = difference_dat & checking if the worksheet was run for the first time today (each subsequent run on the same day does not matter).
However, I have no idea how to check this.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
          i = Range("A2").Value + 1
  End If
End Sub
```

This code would be ok, except that when you run Excel, the entire worksheet recalculates and this disqualifies the result. At the same time, I use other events at startup, so I can't turn them off. Worksheet.SelectionChange also does not pass the result (does not detect the selection when starting Excel).

Cheers

Comment: Recalculation of a function in a cell will not trigger a `Worksheet_Change`  event.

Comment: Yes, but it references a cell (variable) that is associated with Worksheet_Change. As a result, the event is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a Workbook_Open event procedure like this one:-

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ' 289
    
    Dim Ws  As Worksheet
    
    Set Ws = Worksheets("STO_68477673")         ' specify the sheet here
    With Ws.Cells(1, 1)                         ' specify the cell here
        If .Value <> Date Then
        
                
            ' do your updating here
            MsgBox "Updated"
            

            .Value = Date
            .NumberFormat = "dd mmmm, yyyy"     ' change to suit
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The update won't run more than once a day, regardless of how often the workbook is opened and closed. However, you can force an update by deleting the date in A1 and then run the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

1. Store the Date "Somewhere" way out of the way maybe in a hidden sheet *(Get it named ranges pun).*
2. Check it on open

   `IF Range("Somewhere").Value = Date then Exit Sub`
3. Print the result somewhere out of the way what ever metrics you need from this
4. Update the date and have it auto save immediately so no tampering

[image]

You see a named range doesn't need to have a `get activesheet` to be updated, you just call the named range, *that's why we named it*.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way which writes to `Comments` in the `BuiltinDocumentProperties`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Comments")
        If DateValue(.Value) = Date Then
            '~~> Was opened earlier today
        Else
            .Value = Date
            ThisWorkbook.Save
            DoEvents
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use registry and events:

```vb
' in the workbook module
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    IsFirstToday
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)  'if the workbook has not been closed overnight
    If Sh.Name = "Sheet1" Then IsFirstToday
End Sub

' registry root is 'Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\VB and VBA Program Settings'
Private Sub IsFirstToday()
    LastDate = GetSetting(appname:="MyExcelFile", section:="Startup", _
               Key:="LastDate", Default:="01.01.1900")
    If CDate(LastDate) < Date Then
        Debug.Print "Sheet1 activated for the first time today"
        SaveSetting appname:="MyExcelFile", section:="Startup", _
            Key:="LastDate", setting:=Date
    Else
        Debug.Print "Sheet1 activated NOT for the first time today"
    End If
End Sub
```

The registry entry looks like this
[image]